# Why doesn't Hellboy's Rasputin get his eyes back?

Tags: hellboy

In the film *Hellboy*, Rasputin opens Hellboy's portal on the island and mayhem quickly arises. During the fracas,

> Rasputin gets sucked into the portal, but not until bits and pieces (like his eyes) are pulled into the portal first. 60 years after the events on the island, a seemingly fully regenerated Rasputin visits Hellboy. Soonafter, we see Rasputin being groomed by his Nazi minion, who hands him a pair of glass eyes which we see him put in their places.

An answer from the comics or from the film (maybe I missed it) would be great.

> Why doesn't the resurrected Rasputin get his real eyes back?

Answer (score 3):

It's not explained in either the film, or the novelisation. The sole reference to this seems to be a line in the deleted scenes ([and book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_Ziw3r6zjFMC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=hellboy%20%22Your%20eyes.%20What%20did%20they%20do%20to%20your%20eyes&source=bl&ots=7wE_DUgUty&sig=3SFGi2NpKZ8DSZihjAfzYBs3aiU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hAlQVOHHDcWHsQTpyICADA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=hellboy%20%22Your%20eyes.%20What%20did%20they%20do%20to%20your%20eyes&f=false)) where Rasputin arises from Hell in a pool of blood and Ilsa says:

> **"your eyes...what did they do to your eyes?"**

The clear implication being that his eyes were removed when he was in Hell (we assume as part of the regime of torture that he suffered) and have remained there.

[image]